# how we can get query in json

Tags: jquery, python, json

hello every one i have file JSON like this :

```
@service.json
def get_data_physics():
    buuilding_name = ["Zone Test", "Zone Test sans Model"] * 299
    data = {
    "timestamp":["2012-12-08 00:04:53", "2012-12-08 00:09:53", "2012-12-08 00:14:54", "2012-12-08 00:19:54", "2012-12-08 00:24:54", "2012-12-08 00:29:54", "2012-12-08 00:34:54",  "2012-12-09 23:00:46", "2012-12-09 23:05:46", "2012-12-09 23:10:46", "2012-12-09 23:15:46", "2012-12-09 23:20:46", "2012-12-09 23:25:46", "2012-12-09 23:30:46", "2012-12-09 23:35:46", "2012-12-09 23:40:46", "2012-12-09 23:45:47", "2012-12-09 23:50:47", "2012-12-09 23:55:47"],
    "zone_name" : ["lieu Test"] * 575,
    "building_name" : buuilding_name[0:575],
    "outdoor":[3.6, 3.9, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.3, 3.6, 3.6, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.6, 2.6, 3.0, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.3, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.3, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 1.0, 0.7, 0.7],
    "indoor":[13.2, 13.2, 13.1, 13.1, 13.1, 13.1, 13.1, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.9, 13.0, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.8, 12.9, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.6, 12.7, 12.7, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.4, 12.5, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.3, 12.3, 12.4, 12.3, 12.3, 11.7, 11.6, 11.7, 11.7, 11.7, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.7, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.5, 11.6, 11.6, 11.6, 11.5, 11.5, 11.6, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.4, 11.4, 11.5, 11.4, 10.9, 10.9, 10.8, 10.8, 10.9, 10.8, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.9, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6],
    "energy":[41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0],
    "heating":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "presence":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    "daylight":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    }
    print len(data["zone_name"])
    print len(data["building_name"])
    return data
```

i want to get the query on my JSON but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
function createQueryCityName(strUser) { 
    var Query = $.getJSON("call/json/get_data_physics");
        console.log(Query);
        query.setQuery("select building_name where indoor="+ 11.8);
        return query;
        console.log(response);
```

could you tell me what is my problem?

Comment: What exactly does `call/json/get_data_physics` return when you call it directly? Feed it to http://jsonlint.com to see if there's any syntax problems.

Comment: can you take your post with the server side language, please? (Python?)

Comment: getJSON is asynchronous, it is not synchronous. What in the world is `query`, it is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

you need a callback. Do it like

```
$.getJSON('call/json/get_data_physics', function(Query) {

    console.log(Query);

});
```